# Firebase GET_ACCOUNTS Permission crash

Tags: android, firebase, manifest

In my crash report in firebase tell me that "missing permission get_account"

I have get_account in my manifest file and here is my code to request it to the user at runtime

> SplashActivity.class

```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            LayoutInflater lf = (LayoutInflater) this
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View dialogview = lf.inflate(R.layout.access_permission_dialog, null);
            Button ok_btn = (Button) dialogview.findViewById(R.id.ok_btn);
            Button cancel_btn = (Button) dialogview.findViewById(R.id.cancel_btn);
            ok_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    flag = 1;
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                                , Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                                , Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                                , Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                                , Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR
                                , Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS
                                , Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS

                        }, AppConstants.MY_APP_PERMISSIONS);


                    }
```

Any idea why it keeps crashing ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem adding this

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS)
```

This permission is under Contacts as this doc says

[Android Permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html)